# How to change \footnote notation locally in a few places?

Tags: symbols, numbering, footnotes

I like to change the \footnote notation locally in a few places,
see the following, we have

- "Asterisk footnote"
- "Spade footnote"
- "Diamond footnote"

> How do we effectively change \footnote notation locally in a few places?

This is from the example given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392703/change-one-footnote-symbol-from-number-to-asterisk).

```
\begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \hline
        First Name & Dennis \\ \hline
        Last Name & the Menace \footnote{First lettered footnote.} \\ \hline
        Age & 12  \footnote{Asterisk footnote!} \\ \hline
        Major & Math  \footnote{Spade footnote!} \\ \hline
        Sport & Swim  \footnote{Diamond footnote!} \\ \hline
        Music & Chop Suey  \footnote{Second lettered footnote.} \\ \hline
        Shoe size & 15 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption[Denis information.]{Some other description.}
    \label{tab:denisInfo}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Something what `footmisc` package provides? `\DefineFNsymbols` and `\setfnsymbol`, i.e. a set of particular symbols that is used instead of numbers?

Comment: Yes, please give me an example of code? thanks!

Comment: And please leave an answer!

Comment: I only wanted to have some local footnote symbols

Comment: @wonderich: Are you using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) with this implementation? Are these locally-different footnotes only appearing in floats?

Comment: Just any footnote such that I can change their footnote symbols locally, then it does my job...!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the example you borrowed from was suited to footnotes within tabular environment.  For plain text, I used the `mpfootnote` counter to keep track of symbolic footnotes inbetween, with the new command defined as `\symfootnote{}`

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 12pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\newcommand{\symfootnote}[1]{%
\let\oldthefootnote=\thefootnote%
\stepcounter{mpfootnote}%
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}%
\footnote{#1}%
\let\thefootnote=\oldthefootnote%
}

\begin{document}

This document\footnote{first letter} may have 
several\footnote{second letter} 
footnotes\symfootnote{first symbol}. 

While most of them\footnote{third letter} are 
alphabetical\footnote{fourth letter}, some are 
symbolic\symfootnote{second symbol} also, to 
preserve variety\footnote{fifth letter}.

\end{document}
```

This gives an **output :**

[image]

Comment: thanks +1, thanks so much!